# Return a column vector in pandas.apply(), with different length?

Tags: python, pandas, apply

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.percentile([0,10], [10,50,90])
# array([ 1.,  5.,  9.])

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,10], 'b':[0,30]})

print(df)
#     a   b
# 0   0   0
# 1  10  30

​
df.apply(np.percentile, axis=0, q=[10,20,30,40,50,75,100])
```

Should ideally return a dataframe with the relevant percentiles of each column (e.g. column `b=[3,6,9,12,22.5,30]`), but instead I get:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 7), indices imply (2, 2)
```

It seems like pandas either expects apply to return a scalar for each column, or a vector of the same length as the column. Is there a way to return vectors of different length to the original data?

python 3.4.3; pandas 16.1

Answer (score 2):

You can construct a Series from the result:

```
In [27]:

df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.percentile(x, axis=0, q=[10,20,30,40,50,75,100])))
Out[27]:
      a     b
0   1.0   3.0
1   2.0   6.0
2   3.0   9.0
3   4.0  12.0
4   5.0  15.0
5   7.5  22.5
6  10.0  30.0
```

So that it doesn't moan about the incorrect shape

Comment: Great, thanks. I wonder if I should submit a feature request for this to be the default behaviour? (e.g. if result is a 1 dimensional iterable, convert to series).

Answer (score 1):

You should just do this. Simpler (it uses `np.percentile` under the hood).

```
In [9]: df.quantile([.10,.20,.30,.40,.50,.75,1])
Out[9]: 
         a     b
0.10   1.0   3.0
0.20   2.0   6.0
0.30   3.0   9.0
0.40   4.0  12.0
0.50   5.0  15.0
0.75   7.5  22.5
1.00  10.0  30.0
```

Comment: Yes, in this case, but the question is about the general case, with any function that returns a 1D iterable.

Answer (score 0):

You can also turn on `raw`:

```
df.apply(np.percentile, axis=0, q=[10,20,30,40,50,75,100], raw=True)

# a       [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 7.5, 10.0]
# b    [3.0, 6.0, 9.0, 12.0, 15.0, 22.5, 30.0]
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, it raises `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 7), indices imply (2, 2)`

Comment: @EdChum Which versions are you using? I'm using Python 2.7.6 and Pandas 0.16.1 and this runs fine.

Comment: python 3.3.4 64-bit, same pandas version, also numpy 1.9.2, would be useful to know if the OP sees the same error as me

Comment: @EdChum Yes, that error is in the original question.

Comment: @ZiyaoWei: I want a data.frame as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Another version that works the same as EdChum's answer, but splits within `apply`, instead of within `np.percentile`:

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.percentile(x, q=[10,20,30,40,50,75,100])), axis=0)
```

Comment: I submitted a feature request for automatic conversion along these lines: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10260